# Angular material : how to adjust reference betwen two input mat-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-ng-if

I m working under Angular 6 app :

I ve two mat-select inpust which i want to implement a reference betwen them , by the way if my selected option within my **First select**  == the value `'AAA'` 
the **Second** mat-select should be hidden

- First Mat-Select **->**  'AAA'
- Second Mat-Select **->** hidden

I ve tried something like this :

```
       <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col justify-content-start">Mode de chiffrement</label>
          <mat-form-field class="col" >
            <mat-select placeholder="Selectionner le mode de chiffrement" formControlName="modeChiffrement" #FirstSelect>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let modeCh of modeChiffrementData" [value]="modeCh.value">
                {{modeCh.viewValue}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!(FirstSelect== 'AAA')">
            <label class="col justify-content-start">fichiers clés</label>
            <!--<input type="text" formControlName="modeTransfert" class="col form-control"/>-->
            <mat-form-field class="col" >
              <mat-select placeholder="Selectionner fichier" formControlName="fichiersCles">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let modeCh of modeChiffrementData" [value]="modeCh.value">
                  {{modeCh.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

But this is not working

**Ideas ?**

Comment: First solution : `*ngIf="!(FirstSelect.value == 'AAA')"`

Comment: Second solution : `*ngIf="!(myForm.get('modeChiffrement').value == 'AAA')"`

Comment: @trichetriche yeah that's working , if you may put them as responses , to accept them ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference you use is actually a Material Element (put on a `mat-select`).

Because that element [implements](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/select/select.ts#L226) the [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface, you can use it like an `HTMLInputElement`.

This means you should use your condition as

```
*ngIf="!(FirstSelect.value == 'AAA')"
```

Second solution, since you use a reactive form instance, you can simply use

```
*ngIf="!(myForm.get('modeChiffrement').value == 'AAA')"
```